# Underworld layer in Heroes of Might and Magic III

Tags: video-games, might-and-magic

*Might and Magic* has a great lore and *HMM 2*, *MM6*,  *HMM3*, and *MM7* follow a great story line (Kreegans, Ancients etc.).

I wanted to ask about underground layers in [*Heroes of Might and Magic III*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic_III). **Is there any background story, why underground layer exists (I mean like realm of Minotaur etc.)?** Or this feature of *Heroes III* does not have any background story and it is just for fun?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the wiki: [http://mightandmagic.wikia.com/wiki/Underworld](http://mightandmagic.wikia.com/wiki/Underworld)

Though I have no idea how accurate or fleshed out any of that information is.

Comment: I do not recall any "why" being said during first HoMM3 campaign (where demons attack from underground), it was described as something obvious to every in-game character. You might find something in Might&Magic series tho - HoMM3 is supposed to be after MM6.